# Bash Terminal: Write only specific lines to logfile

Tags: bash, logfile

I'm running simulation with lots of terminal output, which would exceed my disc space, if I'd save it to a logfile (e.g by "cmd > logfile"). Now I would like to follow the entire terminal output, but at the same time I would like to save specific data/lines/values from this output to a file.

1) Is there a way to that in bash?

2) Or as alternative: Is it possible to save the logfile, extract the needed data and then delete the processed lines to avoid generating a huge logfile?

Comment: Just `grep` the output...

Comment: @KamilCuk: I don't know if the OP is going to understand your answer: he is new here.

Comment: Read over the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to save into `logfile` only the output containing `mypattern` but you want the see all the output at the terminal, you could issue:

```sh
cmd 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty | grep 'mypattern' > logfile
```

I also assumed that the output of `cmd` may be directed to the standard output stream as well as to the standard error stream, by adding `2>&1` after `cmd`.

Comment: @KamilCuk: You are right. I had to say `/dev/tty`. I will edit my solution.

Comment: `sed` can replace the `tee` *&* the `grep` with one process, but this is a good solution for most folk using the tools they expect.

Comment: @PaulHodges: How do you do that?

Comment: See my solution. `sed` has a `w` option that can be triggered on matching lines.

Comment: @PaulHodges: I learnt something new about `sed` `w` command. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @ Pierre Francois, that was exactly what I was looking for right now!

Comment: @stockzahn: thank you. I read your question again and came to the conclusion that you are looking for the second option I proposed. I will edit my answer to remove the first one, which was not correct by the way.

Answer (score 2):

What criteria are you using to decide which lines to keep?

### 1

One common filter is to just store stderr.

```
cmdlist 2>logfile # stdout still to console
```

### 2

For a more sophisticated filter, if you have specific patterns you want to save to the log, you can use `sed`. Here's a simplistic example -

```
seq 1 100 | sed '/.*[37]$/w tmplog'
```

This will generate numbers from 1 to 100 and send them all to the console, but capture all numbers that end with `3` or `7` to `tmplog`. It can also accept more complex lists of commands to help you be more comprehensive -

```
seq 1 100 | sed '/.*[37]$/w 37.log
                 /^2/w 37.log'
```

c.f. the [`sed` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) for more detailed breakdowns.

You probably *also* want error output, so it might be a good idea to save that too.

```
seq 1 100 2>errlog | sed '/.*[37]$/w patlog'
```

### 3

For a more complex space-saving plan, create a named pipe, and compress the log from that in a background process.

```
$: mkfifo transfer               # creates a queue file on disk that 
$: gzip < transfer > log.gz &    # reads from FIFO in bg, compresses to log
$: seq 1 100 2>&1 | tee transfer # tee writes one copy to stdout, one to file
```

This will show all the output as it comes, but also duplicate a copy to the named pipe; `gzip` will read it from the named pipe and compress it.

#### 3b

You could replace the `tee` with the `sed` for double-dipping space reduction if required -

```
$: mkfifo transfer               
$: gzip < transfer > log.gz &
$: seq 1 100 2>&1 | sed '/.*[37]$/w transfer'
```

I don't really recommend this, as you might filter out something you didn't realize you would need.